# Почему устанавливается 2 приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio, git, github

В общем решил написать небольшое android  приложение,

1) подключил https://github.com/ulogin/Android

2) в settings.gradle прописал

```
include ':uloginsdk'
CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S
```

3) в `Dependencies` выбрал `uloginsdk`

Все компилится, но на телефон ставится 2 приложения: одно - мое, а второе - написано "Выберите способ авторизации". По-моему я что-то не так делаю.

**P.S.** При удалении второго - удаляется и мое

Comment: А вы уверены что 2 приложения с разными пакетами а не просто 2 икноки одного положения?

Comment: Manifest покажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все `Activity`, прописанные в манифесте с фильтром:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

будут отображаться в списке приложений.
При сборке проекта информация из всех манифестов всех зависимостей собирается в итоговый манифест приложения.
О правилах и разрешении конфликтов расписано в гайде: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

В Вашем случае вторая активность-лаунчер прописана в манифесте библиотеки.
Чтобы она не отображалась в списке нужно переопределить её запись в основном манифесте
с атрибутом `tools:node="replace"`:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.ulogin.sdk.UloginAuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        tools:node="replace" >
 </activity>
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать